# MongoDB: How to migrate data from old schema style to new collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema, mongoose-populate

I am sorry if title isn't too clear.

Here's my question

I have this kind of Schema in usermodel.js

```
var messageSchema = new Schema({
to: String,
from: String,
msg: String
});

exports.userSchema = new Schema({
messages = [messageSchema]
})
```

It is running well. But now it needs to changed and another separate collection of messages is required now. So we wanted to make it so that whenever messages are needed, we will populate them.

So user schema would change to

```
exports.userSchema = new Schema({
messages = [{type:Schema.Types.ObjectId,ref:'message'}]
});
```

This will work pretty easy on other new Data. But how to migrate current Message Data to this state.

Thank you